# How to close Facebook Send Dialog (v2.9) automatically after completion?

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs

First, I'm using react and the only way I've found to load a script inside a specific component is by adding it dynamically using reference. I don't like it but the dialog shows up correctly and the message is deliver.

My problems is that the iframe doesn't close automatically after delivering the message.

I've searched in [Send Dialog documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog) and  [Facebook Sdk documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.init/v2.9) but still can't do it.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Thank you

Code:

```
class FbSendDialogComponent extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    const facebookScript = document.createElement('script')
    facebookScript.type = 'text/javascript'
    facebookScript.async = false
    facebookScript.innerHTML = `
    window.fbAsyncInit = () => {
      FB.init({
        appId: 'my app id',
        autoLogAppEvents: true,
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v2.9'
      })
      FB.AppEvents.logPageView()
    }
    (function(d, s, id){
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
     }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));`
    this.node.appendChild(facebookScript)
  }

  openDialog = () => {
    FB.ui({
      method: 'send',
      link: 'https://www.google.com/'
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={(ref) => (this.node = ref)}>
        <h4>You have no connections yet</h4>
        <a onClick={() => this.openDialog()}>Invite</a>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, yeah it's a shame they don't have a `close()` helper method. Sounds like they want you to use a redirect_url for when the user submits the form. An idea would be to redirect to the current page but pass in a `?dialog=close` query param and then in the component you can check the param and use that to handle the open/closed state. Doing a redirect to the current page may actually just go ahead and close it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people who get the same error, I was running my app on localhost and didn't add this domain to my facebook app. I guess facebook failed to redirect you to an unknown domain so it leaves the dialog open.

Answer (score 1):

So you could insert the FB script without using your ref approach by just the running the JS Facebook provides instead of creating a new script element. The creation of a new script element is pretty redundant since you're creating JS to later run JS when you could just run the JS directly. In other words, you could remove that ref you have and do the following in your `componentDidMount` lifecycle method:

```
class FbSendDialogComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    window.fbAsyncInit = () => {
      FB.init({
        appId: '1419915028316261',
        autoLogAppEvents: true,
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v2.9'
      })
      FB.AppEvents.logPageView()
    }

    var js, fjs = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (document.getElementById('facebook-jssdk')) {return;}
    js = document.createElement('script'); js.id = 'facebook-jssdk';
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }

  openDialog() {
    FB.ui({
      method: 'send',
      link: 'https://www.google.com/'
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>You have no connections yet</h4>
        <a onClick={() => this.openDialog()}>Invite</a>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

(I would personally clean up their JS to make it more readable since you probably minify your code at a later point anyway, but the above would still work. I'd also probably extract the `fbAsyncInit` method into a separate module in case I had to do other things, but that's out of the scope of this question.)

In terms of the `iframe` closing after success, I'm not sure what you're referring to. When I run your code locally and click "Invite", the opened dialog closes for me as expected.

Comment: Thank your for the refactoring tips. I still have the popup closing issue though. Since I have no clue to how to fix it, I'll leave it like that for the moment I think.